# Azure devops wiki - Why my image isn't visible for everyone?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

I added an image to the wiki and it looks good for me but not for others.

```
i want to add an image that everyone can see

![obraz.png](https://dev.azure.com/LenoBartek/b6a611eb-fa17-4dcd-89ab-e799f111c78f/_apis/wiki/wikis/a15e5a87-4a17-4419-bd13-d76b5679614a/pages/1/comments/attachments/dd5eceb8-098b-492d-bcc8-e002714886c5)
```

my pov
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilhCX.png)

others pov
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTKLs.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description, You and others should have permission to view the git repo of wiki(Read permission should already been assigned on your side).

So I have a solution that should work.

---

Before giving the solution, I'll start by explaining the makeup of a wiki.

Every DevOps project has a hidden repository, which named **'`<Project Name>.wiki`'**, this repository can't be access via the repository UI list, also can't be listed via the **[List Repositories REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)**. This repository also unable to be managed as other common repositories. Only '**Security for Wiki**'. The repository will store all of the information in the pages of wiki permanently unless you delete the file in the repo.

But the comments section of the wiki is implemented [quite differently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/add-comments-wiki?view=azure-devops#add-a-comment), it is not based on a git repo and does not provide an explicit manage method. If you accidentally delete an image in a comment from the wiki, you won't have any way to get it back.

Depending on what you're in now, you can make others able to view the contents of image like this:

***1, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the image in a test wiki page, save the test page and then get the path of the image:***

[image]

This step will upload the images to the wiki repo and everyone who have access to the wiki repo will be able to see them.

***2, Use the below URL in the comment of wiki:***

`![image.png](https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/<Project Name>/_apis/git/repositories/<Project Name>.wiki/items?scopePath=<The path you get from the above step>&download=true&api-version=6.1-preview.1)`

For example, on my side, it is:

`![image.png](https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/BowmanWikiProject/_apis/git/repositories/BowmanWikiProject.wiki/items?scopePath=.attachments/image-95e808f3-d67d-4060-91fa-836493a761b9.png&download=true&api-version=6.1-preview.1)`

Images using this method will have their own authentication.

Comment: Thanks, it works :)

I also checked that
the image can be manually added to the wiki right away

https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganisation/MyProject/_git/MyProject.wiki
https://imgbox.com/zPtRWdG6

or alternative may be image host
https://blog.appsumo.com/imgur-alternative/

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to >> Settings >> Teams

[image]

Then, Verify your teammates permissions one by one, or create a group which grant permissions to your builds and add all relevant team members